# Не работает приложение на Ogre в режиме отладки

Tags: cmake, codelite

На Ubuntu собрано приложение с помощью CMake, скомпилировано и слинковано на g++, в результате все работает и запускается непосредственно с ФМ. Но стоит только запустить его через Debugger, то в окне конфигурации нет ни одного доступного рендера, в следствии чего приложение вылетает.

[image: ogre debug]
[image: ogre debug]

Как правильно настроить среду(в моем случае codelite) для отладки?

Comment: попробуйте проделать как здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742217/cmake-debug-сборка-в-qtcreator-для-qt4-8-7 может будут какие нибудь подвижки, или укажите свои настройки cmake