# cmake debug сборка в QtCreator для Qt4.8.7

Tags: linux, qtcreator, cmake

Ubuntu 16.04 64. Qt Creator 3.5.1, Qt4.8.7. открыл [проект на cmake](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740192/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-qt4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-cmake-ubuntu-16-04), однако не получается произвести полноценный дебаг. После чтения main.cpp дебаг завершается а программа запускается.

В файл CMakeLists.txt (верхнего уровня для проекта и верхнего для исходников, т.е. в два файла добавил одно и тоже) [добавил](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724569/debug-vs-release-in-cmake)([ещё источник](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-March/020347.html)):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")

if( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
  set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING
       "Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
MinSizeRel."
       FORCE )
endif()
```

Используя мастер cmake использовал команды:

```
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4 -DCMAKE_BUILD=Debug
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G Ninja
```

использовал [дополнительные параметры](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/cmake-or-make-debug-output-show-command-624800/) ([ещё](http://rus-linux.net/nlib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/gnu_make/gnu_make_3-79_russian_manual.html)) make:

```
-j4 VERBOSE=1 -d
```

Пробую запустить отладку через gdb используюя QtCreator напрямую к запущенному приложению. В результате через некоторое время выходит сообщение:

> Процесс gdb не отвечает на команду в течение 40 секунд. Это может
>   означать, что он попал в бесконечный цикл, или исполнение операции
>   занимает больше времени, чем предполагается. Вы можете продолжить
>   ожидание или прервать отладку.

Процесс отладки при этом ничего не отображал, кроме факта подключения и отключения. В консольной версии gdb после стартовой отладочной информации появлялось только следующее сообщение:

```
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
```

Comment: Судя по https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1904, название генератора должно быть заключено в кавычки. Поищите в каталоге сборки программы файл, в котором встречается слово `GCodeBlocks` (Notepad++ и Sublime Text умеют искать по содержимому всех файлов в указанном каталоге, только выберите рекурсивный поиск). Вполне возможно, что Qt забыл поставить кавычки при передаче внутренних параметров.